# ASP Classic- split() by value for multi select

Tags: split, asp-classic

I have multiple select as below:

```
<select name="fnme" onchange="myFnm()" multiple>
  <option value="STR12(12,YU,IO)">STR12(12,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR13(13,YU,IO)">STR12(13,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR14(14,YU,IO)">STR12(14,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR15(15,YU,IO)">STR12(15,YU,IO)</option>
</select>
```

ASP code:

```
<%
dim fnm,element
fnm=Split(Request("fnme"),",")
for each element in fnm
  Response.Write("<p>--qq-- " & element & " </p>")
Next
%>
```

When I select "STR12(12,YU,IO)" and "STR12(13,YU,IO)" , the output will become like this:

```
--qq-- STR12(12 

--qq-- YU

--qq-- IO)

--qq-- STR13(13 

--qq-- YU

--qq-- IO)
```

Instead of this kind of output I want the output to be like this:

```
--qq-- STR12(12,YU,IO)

--qq-- STR12(13,YU,IO)
```

Comment: Just remove the `Split()`, use `fnm = Request.Form("fnme")`.

Comment: @Lankymart it will have error said Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c3' 

Object not a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would add a delimiter to the end of each value, like so:

```
<select name="fnme" onchange="myFnm()" multiple>
  <option value="STR12(12,YU,IO)|">STR12(12,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR13(13,YU,IO)|">STR12(13,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR14(14,YU,IO)|">STR12(14,YU,IO)</option>
  <option value="STR15(15,YU,IO)|">STR12(15,YU,IO)</option>
</select>
```

then, your ASP code would be:

```
<%
dim fnm,element
fnm=Split(fnme,"|,")
for each element in fnm
   if element <> "" then
      if Right( element, 1 ) = "|" then element = Left( element, Len( element ) - 1 )
      Response.Write("<p>--qq-- " & element & " </p>")
   end if
Next
%>
```

Comment: i add it and it works just the output will be --qq-- STR12(12,YU,IO) 

--qq-- , STR13(13,YU,IO) 

--qq-- , STR14(14,YU,IO) 

--qq-- , STR15(15,YU,IO) is there any way we can remove "," for the new line?

Comment: try changing

if element <> "" then

to

if Trim( element ) <> "" then

Comment: still doesn't change

Comment: i updated my previous code to get rid of the extra commas

Comment: I think this is better although there will be --qq-- STR15(15,YU,IO)| for the last selection

Comment: my pleasure  :-)